# Stopping time of dependent gaussians variables

Tags: random-variables, normal-distribution, stopping-times

I struggle proving a proposition. Assume that

$$T=\inf \{ n > 0 : X_n \leq 0 \}$$

Where $X_{n+1}=X_n+ Y_{n+1}$ and $(Y_n)$ are **independent** gaussians random variables $\mathcal{N}(\mu_n, \sigma_n^2)$. I would like to find a sufficient condition such that
$$\mathbb{E}(T)=\infty$$
I first tried with basic definition of expectation where
$$\mathbb{P}(T=n)=\mathbb{P} \left( \bigcap_{k=0}^{n-1} \{ X_k > 0\} \cap \{ X_n \leq 0 \} \right)$$
$$\mathbb{P}(T=n)=\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} \mathbb{P}(X_0 > 0, \dots, X_k > 0 | X_{k+1} > 0, \dots, X_n \leq 0)\mathbb{P}(X_n \leq 0)$$
But I encounter difficulties since $(X_n)$ are not independent variables.
If you have any advice or idea to express the expectation in a better way (I found articles on Wald's identity but can't use it on my problem), I would be extremely grateful.
Thanks again for your time.

Comment: I forgot to mention that $X_0=0$ a.s.